# Get IMethod from the method name in java

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-jdt

I'm looking for a way to find the IMethod, given the method name as input for developing my eclipse plugin further.

Couldn't figure out a way to do so.

can someone please direct me in the right path.

Comment: Method name is not unique, methods with same name can exist in the same class (overloading) or other classes. What else do you pass as input to your plug-in?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can give the method name along with the parameters to differentiate from other methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two approaches:

1. You can use the `ASTVisitor` pattern to visit the `MethodDeclaration` nodes, do a check for name and arguments, and get `IMethod` from them by resolving the binding. Refer the below posts:

   - [Eclipse create CompilationUnit from .java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166862/eclipse-create-compilationunit-from-java-file/11168301#11168301)
   - [How to convert AST to JDT Java model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813202/how-to-convert-ast-to-jdt-java-model/15827754#15827754)
2. Get the `IType`s from the compilation unit and loop through the `IMethods`, do check for name and arguments to find the required one.

   ```
   IType [] typeDeclarationList = unit.getTypes();
   for (IType typeDeclaration : typeDeclarationList) {
      // Get methods under each type declaration.
      IMethod [] methodList = typeDeclaration.getMethods();
      for (IMethod method : methodList) {
         // Logic here.
      }
   }
   ```